# Unable to ssh into Amazon EC2 instance after running high memory consuming script

Tags: amazon-ec2

I run a python script on an EC2 instance, which occupied most of its RAM. Gradually it became slow and I lost connection. I can't ssh into the EC2 instance anymore. I also tried SSH remote kill. But neither of them work.
How can I kill the process remotely?

Comment: You would need to ssh to to kill the process. I would suggest restart the instance and then try to ssh into the instance.

Comment: Is there any other way apart from restarting? I have mysql running on the instance. After I restart, I do not get DB connection.

Comment: If your python process just continues to run, then there really isn't any other way.   You'll need to restart the instance as suggested, and also start up the mysql process as well.

Comment: After reboot, scp isn't working.. I had the same issue earlier also!

Answer (score 0):

Here the easiest solution is to Restart the instance as you will not be able to kill the memory consuming processes, or free up the memory without SSHing into it.